# Mocking New Object Call In Superclass

Tags: junit, powermockito

I am having a hard time getting this one piece of mocking figured out for my unit tests. The classes in question are all part of legacy code that I don't really have the option of changing right now (I am hoping to be able to do some refactoring in the future, but need tests now).

Here are the two classes that I am dealing with, and the specific part I am having trouble with. Class A declares an object using `new` and then class B uses the object. I am trying to mock the object but I keep getting the real version of it instead of the mocked version.

```
public class B extends A(){
  ...
  int x = problemObj.doMethod();
}
public class A(){
  ...
  ProblemObj problemObj = new ProblemObj();
}
```

Here is my test class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class, B.class})
public class ATest(){
  private ProblemObj problemObjMock;

  @Before
  public void setUp(){
    problemObj = PowerMockito.Mock(ProblemObj.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void test(){

    PowerMockito.whenNew(ProblemObj.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(problemObj);
    ...//rest of test below here
  }
}
```

I have done other `whenNew` mocking in tests and set it up the same way as this. But for some reason this object being in the superclass is really throwing me off.

Versions used are Junit:4.11, Mockito:1.9.5, Powermock: 1.6.6

Comment: Can you be specific about what "nothing I have tried is working so far" means? Are you getting an exception? If so, could you update your question with the stacktrace? If you are not getting an exception, could you describe exactly what 'not working' means in this case? It would also help if you listed the versions of JUnit, Mockito and PowerMock in use here. FWIW, I can get the above code working (i.e. successfully mocking `ProblemObj`) using `junit:4.12`, `mockito-all:2.7.19` and `powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0`.

Comment: I can get the above code working (i.e. successfully mocking ProblemObj) using `junit:4.12`, `mockito-all:2.7.19` and `powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0`.

Comment: @glytching Updated with the versions I am using. I am pretty much stuck on them until the enterprise approves newer versions, so if mockito 1.x can't handle this scenario I might have to find a work around.